# gdb no muestra la linea que está causando el segfault c++

Tags: c++, gdb, segfault

Estoy haciendo un programa c++ que resulta en segmentation fault.
Para encontrar dónde está el problema estoy siguiendo los siguientes pasos:

$ g++ -g *.cpp -std=c++20

$ gdb ./a.out

(gdb) r

y me muestra esto:

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7ed94c4 in std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits >& std::operator<<
<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::cha
r_traits >&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocat
or > const&) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6

La verdad no tengo la menor idea de lo que esto significa, yo solo quiero que me muestre en qué archivo y en qué línea está el error

Answer (score 2):

Aunque suene a chino:

```
std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits >& std::operator<< <char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::cha r_traits >&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocat or > const&) ()
```

Es una sobrecarga del operador << para un `ostream` y un `string`. Por ejemplo, un código como el siguiente llama a esa función:

```
std::string s;
std::cout << s;
```

Cuando ocurre un error, gdb informa la línea en la que ocurrió y como esa línea forma parte de la librería estándar simplemente no tienes idea de qué lo causa.

Tendrás que ayudarte de otros comandos como:

- `backtrace` muestra la pila de llamadas.
- `print` imprime el resultado de una expresión o una variable.
- `info` obtiene información sobre parámetros, registros y otras cosas.
- `frame` para moverte por la pila de llamadas.

Aquí tienes algunos enlaces sobre gdb:

- https://gist.github.com/rkubik/b96c23bd8ed58333de37f2b8cd052c30
- https://darkdust.net/writings/gdb

Comment: Muchas gracias. El problema resultó ser:     std:::cout  << variable_no_inicializada << '/n';

Comment: Las variables no inicializadas siempre dando problemas. Prueba compilar con `-Wuninitialized` para que aparezcan advertencias cuando se te olvide inicializar alguna.